# Deploying CloudWatch Agent Config to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have two environments (production, staging) within an Elastic Beanstalk environment and wanted to set up CloudWatch Agent logging for the EC2 instances being used with these environments. When reading the [EB Cloudwatch logs how to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html), the process seemed relatively straightforward with only two modifications required, adding an IAM permission for the CloudWatch Log to EB instance profile and adding three config files to `.ebextensions`. However I'm not sure if I am deploying the newly added config files correctly. I simply restarted the instance rather than run `eb deploy` and it doesn't appear from the CloudWatch interface that any agent is installed. Will config additions to `.ebextensions` only be applied when running `eb deploy`?